Remove Null if Match
Table A



Column1
Column2
column3




Mobile
group_filtering
on


Mobile
offer_group
1619


Mobile
country_code
0


Lan
duration
10


Lan
type
auto



Table B



ID
Name
Description




1619
B2B
B2B Club



Expected Output:



Column1
Name




Mobile
B2B


Lan




Query : select distinct table1.column1,table2.name from table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 on table1.column3 = table2.id
Result



Column1
Name




Mobile
B2B


Mobile



Lan




Note : Table having many more rows and columns

Please [edit] the question to show actual table definitions (CREATE TABLE scripts) with only relevant columns, sample data as INSERT scripts, your Postgres version, and explain what the query is supposed to do. Don't make us guess.

Divide et impera - with a CTE:
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.column1, t2.name
   FROM   table1 t1
   LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.column3 = t2.id
   )
SELECT column1, name
FROM   cte
WHERE  name IS NOT NULL  -- filter all nulls

UNION ALL                -- add back 1 row, where all names are null
SELECT column1, null
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY column1
HAVING count(name) = 0
;

Notably, count() does not count null values.
Depending on undisclosed table definitions, the query might be optimized ...
